# What happened to the authors of 'Modern Quantum Chemistry"?

Tags: books

This is kind of a silly question, but my google-fu has failed me, and I can think of no better place to ask it:

What ever happened to the authors of the classic "Modern Quantum Chemistry", Attila Szabo and Neil S. Ostlund? I notice that they were faculty at IU and University of Arkansas, respectively, but see no mention of their retirement or anything else. Are they still with us today? If so, what are they up to?

Comment: Not really a silly question but very broad.  I will let it stand in the off chance that someone is a colleague.  The chances of that are fairly slim, though.

Comment: If I remember correctly,  Neil S. Ostlund moved to the University of Waterloo and then founded HyperCube Inc., known for HyperChem, at the same location.

Comment: I just googled "Attila Szabo" and landed on an NIH page [here](http://irp.nih.gov/pi/attila-szabo).

Comment: Ostlund also recently started [Chemical Semantics](http://chemicalsemantics.com/about-us/) which is a startup claiming to bring semantic web technologies to computational chemistry.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt - I came up with this search as well, but  found no mention of the book in his list of publication/works, so assumed it was not him.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison - Very cool. I had no idea this existed. I guess that answers my question then.